# "Export to Word" DotCMS Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, dotcms

I am developing "Export to Word" [DotCMS dynamic plugin](https://dotcms.com/docs/latest/osgi-plugins) that allow users to export **page content** into Word Processing document using [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/java/word-component.aspx) library. I am exploring DotCMS documentation for last one week and have fixed most of the bottlenecks except following:
"**How I can read contents of a particular page?**"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this via API is to call the HTMLPageAssetAPI.getHTML() methods.

There are a number of overloaded methods but something like this returns the page content as a String:

```
APILocator.getHTMLPageAssetAPI().getHTML(htmlPage, userAgent)
```